# Urwid filtering in key presses/filtering out mouse clicks

Tags: python-3.x, urwid

I'm putting together a little console application using Urwid. I've used the pattern described in the Urwid tutorial (see, http://urwid.org/tutorial/) to handle key press events.

For example

```
def on_unhandled_input(key):
    elif key in ('n'):
        create_new()
    elif key in ('q'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()

main_loop = urwid.MainLoop(layout, unhandled_input=on_unhandled_input)
main_loop.run()
```

My problem is that the unhandled_input appears to capture mouse clicks, which causes my handler to error out with

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

What is the best way to filter for key presses and discard the mouse clicks?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the syntax `('n')` and `('q')` are creating strings instead of tuples.
For keys it's not a problem because the `in` operator works for checking if strings are inside of string:

```
>>> 'n' in 'n'
True
>>> 'n' in ('n')
True
```

But this fails with an error:

```
>>> ('mouse', 'right') in ('n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

To solve the problem, you can add a comma for the tuple syntax, try with:

```
def on_unhandled_input(key):
    elif key in ('n',):  # <-- notice the added comma here
        create_new()
    elif key in ('q',):  # <-- and here too
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
```

As an alternative, you could just use `==` to do the comparison:

```
def on_unhandled_input(key):
    elif key == 'n':  # <-- notice the added comma here
        create_new()
    elif key == 'q':  # <-- and here too
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
```